# ERC-721: does restricting addresses to having only one ERC-721 also restrict trading in the future?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft

This is probably a dumb question, but just to make sure.
I'm building an ERC-721 contract that should only be able to mint one token per address. But afterwards trading shouldn't be restricted.

Using sol's "Mapping" and some basic logic to do so, would that also restrict trading of the ERC-721 afterwards?

Thank you.

Comment: to restrict trading you have to block the change of the ownership. So your token should be assigned to one person and stay like this forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are proposing is workable.

Have a bit set for each address. Set it to one when minting. And require it to be zero before minting.